# Offset with ajax load more posts duplicates

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, ajax, query

I have a shortcode that gets posts. I am using the shortcode three times on the page. The first time I grab the first 6 posts, the second time I offset by 6 and grab the next 4 posts, the third time I offset by 10 and grab the next 8 but this time I have a load more button to keep adding 8 until all posts are showing.

When I hit the Load More button it duplicates that last two posts from the previous 8. So in this third section I have posts 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. When I hit the load more button I get 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14

I have concluded that this has to do with the offset and my post per page. My post per page count is 8 but the query starts by offsetting 10.

If I change the offset to 8 I no longer have any duplicates.

below is my code:

```
add_shortcode( 'articles-grid', 'articles_grid' );
function articles_grid( $atts ) {

    $showdate = $showauthor = $showexcerpt = $post_excerpt = $post_meta = $post_author = $post_seperator = $post_published = $has_featured_article = $data_class = $results = $trend_class = '';

    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        'offset'        => 0,
        'showdate'      => null,
        'trending'      => null,
        'category'      => null,
        'exclude'       => null,
        'showauthor'    => null,
        'showexcerpt'   => null,
        'init'          => 1
    ), $atts ) );

    $exclude_ids = array_map('intval', explode(',', $exclude));

    $exclude_featured = array(391);

    $exclude_cats = array_merge($exclude_featured,$exclude_ids);

    ob_start();

    if($trending) 
        $posts_per_page = 6;
    else
        $posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'offset' => $offset,
        'category__not_in' => $exclude_cats,
        'category__in' => $category,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { 

        $published_posts = $query->found_posts;
        $page_number_max = ceil($published_posts / $posts_per_page);
    ?>
        <div id="main-posts" class="ajax_posts">
            <?php 
                $all_post_cats = array();
                $count = 1;
            ?>
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                $cats = get_the_category(get_the_ID());
                $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'full');

                $posted_time_diff = human_time_diff( get_the_time('U',get_the_ID()), current_time('timestamp') );

                $author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', get_the_ID());
                $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id );

                $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(get_the_ID());

                $seperator = ' | ';

                if($showdate || $showauthor) {

                    if($showauthor) {

                        $story_author = get_field( "story_author", get_the_ID() );

                        if($story_author) {
                            $post_author = ' ' . esc_html__( '', 'et_builder' ) . 'By <span class="author">' . $story_author . '</span>';
                        } else {
                            $post_author = et_get_safe_localization( sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'et_builder' ), 'By <span class="author">' . esc_html( $author_name ) . ' </span>' ) );
                        }

                    }

                    if($showdate && $showauthor) {

                        $post_seperator = $seperator;

                    }

                    if($showdate) {

                        $post_published = et_get_safe_localization( sprintf( __( '%s', 'et_builder' ), '<span class="published">' . esc_html( $posted_time_diff ) . ' ago </span>' ) );

                    }

                    if($showexcerpt) {

                        $post_excerpt = et_get_safe_localization( sprintf( __( '%s', 'et_builder' ), '<p class="post-meta post-excerpt"><span class="excerpt">' . esc_html( $excerpt ) . '</span></p>' ) );

                    }

                    $post_meta = '<p class="post-meta">'.$post_author.$post_seperator.$post_published.'</p>'.$post_excerpt;

                }

                foreach($cats as $cat) {
                    if($cat->term_id != 391)
                        $all_post_cats[] = 'cat-'.$cat->slug;
                }

                if ($count % $posts_per_page == 1) {  
                    echo '<div id="" class="recent-posts-grid-container">';
                }
                ?>

                <article class="<?php echo $count; ?> recent-article <?php echo implode(' ',$all_post_cats); ?>">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <div class="recent-post-featured-image-container">   
                                <div class="recent-post-featured-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumb; ?>)"></div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="recent-post-content">
                                <div class="recent-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                                <?php echo $post_meta; ?>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                </article>

                <?php

                if ($count % $posts_per_page == 0) {  
                    echo "</div>";
                }

                $count++;

                unset($all_post_cats);
                ?>

                <?php
                    if($trending) {

                        echo '<article class="trending-container '.$trend_class.'"><h2>Trending</h2>'.do_shortcode('[wpp cat="-394" range="last7days" limit=6 stats_views=1 order_by="views" excerpt_length=110 post_html=\'<li>{title}</li>\']').'</article>';

                    }
                ?>

            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


        </div>

        <?php
            // don't display the button if there are not enough posts
            if (  $page_number_max > 1 ) :
                echo '<div class="load-more-posts-btn-container"><a href="#" class="load-more-posts" data-showauthor="'.$showauthor.'" data-showdate="'.$showdate.'" data-trending="'.$trending.'" data-showexcerpt="'.$showexcerpt.'" data-paged="'.$init.'" data-exclude="['.implode(',',$exclude_cats).']" data-ppp="'.$posts_per_page.'">More Stories</a></div>';
            endif;
        ?>

    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
        return $myvariable;

    }

}
```

This is the function called by ajax to load more:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'categories_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'categories_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}

function categories_loadmore_ajax_handler(){

    $showdate = $showauthor = $showexcerpt = $post_excerpt = $post_meta = $post_author = $post_seperator = $post_published = $has_featured_article = $data_class = $results = $trend_class = '';

    $showdate = $_POST['showdate'];
    $showauthor = $_POST['showauthor'];
    $trending = $_POST['trending'];
    $showexcerpt = $_POST['showexcerpt'];

    if(isset($_POST['posts_per_page']))

        $posts_per_page = $_POST['posts_per_page'];

    else {

        if($trending) 
            $posts_per_page = 9;
        else
            $posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

    }

    $args = array(
        'cat' => $_POST['cat'],
        'category__not_in' => $_POST['exclude'],
        'paged' => $_POST['page'] + 1,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    // it is always better to use WP_Query but not here
    query_posts( $args );

    if( have_posts() ) :

        $all_post_cats = array();
        $count = 1;

        // run the loop
        while( have_posts() ): the_post();

            // $trending= 1;
            // $showdate = 0;
            // $showauthor = 1;
            $cats = get_the_category(get_the_ID());
            $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'full');

            $posted_time_diff = human_time_diff( get_the_time('U',get_the_ID()), current_time('timestamp') );

            $author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', get_the_ID());
            $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id );

            $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(get_the_ID());

            $seperator = ' | ';

            if($showdate || $showauthor) {

                if($showauthor) {

                    $story_author = get_field( "story_author", get_the_ID() );

                    if ( function_exists( 'coauthors_posts_links' ) ) {
                        $post_author = coauthors_posts_links($between = null, $betweenLast = "&nbsp;and&nbsp;", $before = "By&nbsp;", $after = null, $echo = false);
                    } else {
                        $post_author = et_get_safe_localization( sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'et_builder' ), 'By <span class="author">' . esc_html( $author_name ) . ' </span>' ) );
                    }

                }

                if($showdate && $showauthor) {

                    $post_seperator = $seperator;

                }

                if($showdate) {

                    $post_published = et_get_safe_localization( sprintf( __( '%s', 'et_builder' ), '<span class="published">' . esc_html( $posted_time_diff ) . ' ago </span>' ) );

                }

                if($showexcerpt) {

                    $post_excerpt = et_get_safe_localization( sprintf( __( '%s', 'et_builder' ), '<p class="post-meta post-excerpt"><span class="excerpt">' . esc_html( $excerpt ) . '</span></p>' ) );

                }

                $post_meta = '<p class="post-meta">'.$post_author.$post_seperator.$post_published.'</p>'.$post_excerpt;

            }

            foreach($cats as $cat) {
                if($cat->term_id != 391)
                    $all_post_cats[] = 'cat-'.$cat->slug;
            }

            if ($count % $posts_per_page == 1) {  
                echo '<div id="" class="recent-posts-grid-container">';
            }

            ?>

            <article class="<?php echo $count; ?> recent-article <?php echo implode(' ',$all_post_cats); ?>">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="recent-post-featured-image-container">   
                            <div class="recent-post-featured-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumb; ?>)"></div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="recent-post-content">
                            <div class="recent-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                            <?php echo $post_meta; ?>
                        </div>
                    </a>
            </article>

            <?php
                if($trending) {

                    echo '<article class="trending-container hide-trending"></article>';

                }
            ?>

            <?php 

            if ($count % $posts_per_page == 0) {  
                echo "</div>";
            }

        $count++;

        unset($all_post_cats);

        endwhile;

    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    die; // here we exit the script and even no wp_reset_query() required!
}
```

Comment: And your question is...? As far as I understand, you've already solved your problem by setting offset to 8?

Comment: Read the first part. I can’t change the offset to be 8 because I am using the first 10 posts via the first and second function calls. If I use offset 8 then I would have a duplicate of posts 1,2 instead of 7,8

Comment: OK, but functions can have params and you can pass them as request data...

Comment: Yes as you can see in the second function I am already doing that

Comment: Well... No, you don’t. You don’t set offset anywhere in your AJAX callback function... You set page and posts_per_page, so you ignore the count of posts that is already printed...

Comment: Can you give some code demonstrating?